# Index out of bounds, error in IF line of code

Tags: java, eclipse

So, this code is supposed to do the following:
Check if the neighboring members in a row of the square matrix and write them if their sum is an even number and also write the members which sum is a odd number. But it sends an error in the first if statement. But it only does the first row and outputs the Index out of bounds. Here is the code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Ucitati broj clanova kvadratne matrice: ");
    int n = scan.nextInt();
    int niz[][] = new int[n][n];
    System.out.println("Ucitati clanove matrice: ");
    for (int i = 0; i < niz.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < niz.length; j++) {
            System.out.print("n[" + i + ", " + j + "]" + "=");
            niz[i][j] = scan.nextInt();
        }
    }
    System.out.println();

    for (int i = 0; i < niz.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < niz.length; j++) {
            System.out.print(niz[i][j] + " ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }

    System.out.println("Susedni clanovi cija je suma parna su: ");
    for (int i = 0; i < niz.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < niz.length; j++) {
            if ((niz[i][j] + niz[i][j + 1]) % 2 == 0) {
                System.out.print(niz[i][j] + " " + niz[i][j + 1] + "; ");

            }
        }
    }

    System.out.println("Susedni clanovi cija je suma neparna su: ");
    for (int i = 0; i < niz.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < niz.length; j++) {
            if ((niz[i][j] + niz[i][j + 1]) % 2 != 0) {
                System.out.print(niz[i][j] + " " + niz[i][j + 1] + "; ");

            }
        }
    }
}
```

System.out.println are in Serbian so if u need a translate let me know, but that shouldn't be needed.

Comment: in `niz[i][j+1]` the `j+1` goes beyond the size of the array, you probably need `for (int j = 0; j < niz.length - 1; j++)`

Comment: Tried it, that doesn't work either.

Comment: In addition, you have 4x mistakenly `j < niz.length` probably instead of `j < niz[i].length`.

Comment: What is your input test case where it is failing ?

Comment: @howlger his array is [n][n] so I agree with you it would be cleaner, but for me the `j < niz.length` is working

Comment: @Zinc You are right. I overlooked that.

Comment: @Jovke Well, it doesn't look like you did that. In `for (int j = 0; j < niz.length - 1; j++)` `niz[i][j+1]` will lead to j=n and therefore to the index out of bounds. So, fix that.

Comment: @Zinc actually it worked but i added them into last 2 for loops instead of only one as i originally did. Thanks guys for help.